# How to set a google maps marker with user image in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-drawable

I'm implementing a GPS tracking application.in that application i need to set a google maps marker with specific user image masked in marker.

Attached is the example of markers with user profile images . i want to achieve  something similar

[image: Like This]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to set Google marker as image. You can find the similar project which has Google marker as image in github.
link is [enter link description here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

In this link 'clustering custom look' is for Google marker as image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BitmapDescriptorFactory` to load and create custom marker icons:

```
new MarkerOptions()
    .position(latlng)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resId))
```

`BitmapDescriptorFactory` declarations:

```
public static BitmapDescriptor fromResource(int resourceId)
public static BitmapDescriptor fromAsset(String assetName)
public static BitmapDescriptor fromFile(String fileName) 
public static BitmapDescriptor fromPath(String absolutePath)
public static BitmapDescriptor fromBitmap(Bitmap image)
```